# Synonym/retag [ecs] -> [amazon-ecs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecs) is a duplicate of [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs).  It has fewer questions and doesn't follow convention for AWS-related tags (`amazon-*`).

I've never done any sort of meta-related work before (such as retagging), so I want to make sure I'm following the correct procedures.  I'm not sure whether this should be a synonym request or a retag request.

- [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs): 102 questions
- [ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecs): 42 questions

Comment: @yellowantphil That would probably be ideal.  I'm not really familiar with the terminology or the options that are available.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the synonym is now in place.